# Batch Export to JPEG with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, export

I have a folder of 28 mxds that I'm trying to export all of them into 28 JPEGs. I'm having difficulty with the script and I'm hoping someone can help figure where I went wrong. Basically, I want to be export to run automatically, so that I don't have to open each mxd to export them into JPEGs.

```
    import arcpy, os
>>> folderPath = r"H:\Users\2015\Map15-0001\Zone Maps - for External Website"
>>> for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
...     fullpath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
...     if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
...         basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
...         if extension.lower() == ".mxd":
...             mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
...             df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
...             arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"H:\Users\2015\Map15-0001\Zone Maps - for External Website\New"+basename+".jpg", df,resolution = 1000)
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1026, in ExportToJPEG
    layout.exportToJPEG(*args)
AttributeError: DataFrameObject: Error in parsing arguments for ExportToJPEG
```

The mxds all have Data Driven Pages running on them. I was able to previously take all of the mxds and export separate PDFs.

I'm running ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: Do they all have dataframes "Layers"?

Comment: Yes, they all do. Also, all the mxds have an inset map with the generic "new data frame". Does that make a difference?

Comment: I'd experiment with 1st in a list by disabling data pages and export without dataframes. Break loop to save time when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your code and subsequent comments it sounds like you want to export the layout rather than the dataframe? If so simply replace the `df` object with the string "PAGE_LAYOUT" in [ExportToJPEG()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttojpeg.htm#S2_GUID-A061A555-079F-4EAC-AF40-BA31A89C2E23).

Answer (score 0):

I think the concatenation is messing up in your export to jpeg call. Try using formatting instead of concatenation:

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, "H:\\Users\\2015\\Map15-0001\\Zone Maps - for External Website\\New{0}.jpg".format(basename), df,resolution = 1000)
```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting